# How to call a self-defined command line function in Python

Tags: python, bash, command-line, os.system

I'm trying to call a self-defined command line function in python. I defined my function using apple script in `/.bash_profile` as follows:

```
function vpn-connect  {
/usr/bin/env osascript <<-EOF
tell application "System Events"
        tell current location of network preferences
                set VPN to service "YESVPN" -- your VPN name here
                if exists VPN then connect VPN
                repeat while (current configuration of VPN is not connected)
                    delay 1
                end repeat
        end tell
end tell
EOF
}
```

And when I tested `$ vpn-connect` in `bash`, `vpn-connect` works fine. My vpn connection is good.

So I created `vpn.py` which has following code:

```
import os

os.system("echo 'It is running.'")
os.system("vpn-connect")
```

I run it with `python vpn.py` and got the following output:

```
vpn Choushishi$ python vpn.py 
It is running.
sh: vpn-connect: command not found
```

This proves calling self-defined function is somehow different from calling the ones that's pre-defined by the system. I have looked into `pydoc os` but couldn't find useful information.

Comment: I suspect this has to do with the fact that `os.system` starts a subshell, and .bash_profile is not read for non-login shells, but I don't know why the existing function would not be visible in the subshell.

Comment: You might want to look at [interfacing with AppleScript directly from Python](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/macosa.html), rather than using a shell script as an intermediary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A way would be to read the ./bash_profile before. As @anishsane pointed out you can do this:

   ```
   vpn=subprocess.Popen(["bash"],shell=True,stdin= subprocess.PIPE)
   vpn.communicate("source /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/.bash_profile;vpn-connect")
   ```
2. or with os.system

   ```
   os.system('bash -c "source /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/.bash_profile;vpn-connect"')
   ```
3. Or try

   ```
   import subprocess
   subprocess.call(['vpn-connect'], shell = True)
   ```
4. and try

   ```
   import os
   os.system('bash -c vpn-connect')
   ```

   according to http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: `os.system('bash -c "source /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/.bash_profile;vpn-connect"')` works. Thanks!

Comment: Another option would be to use `vpn=subprocess.Popen(["bash"],shell=True,stdin= subprocess.PIPE);vpn.communicate("vpn-connect");`